# Spring MVC Project error in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

In Spring Tool Suite 3.9.5, After Selecting New -> Project -> Spring Legacy Project -> Spring MVC Project. project is created but with errors. I even tried Maven -> Update Project but issues still exists.

[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfssZ.png)

[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBOSB.png)

I have not installed Maven. I am using jdk 1.8

Comment: try to include screenshot of problems panel to let us know what is your issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed repository folder's files from m2 folder. STS is now making Spring MVC Project without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as you are developing a Web project, most probably you are missing servlet.jar and other related web jars. So please proceed as follows:

1. Add following dependencies in your **POM** file with proper versions. Save the file.

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Do **Maven** -> **Update Project** (Install **Maven** in your system if not done)
3. Do a project clean build by going to **Project** -> **Clean...**
4. All error marks should go away by now. If not, go to Problem view by selecting **Window** -> **Show View** -> **Problems**
5. There check the issues in your project. Accordingly update the **POM** or change classpath. Now repeat steps 2 and 3.

**EDIT :**

It seems the following dependencies are missing for your project. Add these in your **POM** and follow the above steps.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Then Maven is not updating jars properly. So install Maven first.

Comment: Does'nt STS has built in Maven? or do i have to install maven separately?

Comment: STS supports Maven. So you have to install it separately. More info you can get at http://maven.apache.org/